# sort elements from 1d array into triangular matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, triangular

I am trying to move the elements from 1d array (55,) made up of

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3,
       4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4,
       5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]).
```

I want to organize this 1d array into a formation like the following:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0],
 [0]]
```

so I want to end up with this:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2],
 [1]]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this? Also note that I want to do this for a large array of 325K elements to organize it into 807 distinct rows.

Comment: Can't you do this with lists?  Efficiency shouldn't be your initial goal.  What you seek is not a multidimensional  numpy array.

Comment: Numpy does not accept a non-rectangular array. if you insist on variable length elements, your elements has to be objects like lists. In other words, you cannot have multidimensional array like the output you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know exactly how many items you want in your first row you can do this

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3,
       4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4,
       5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1])

b = []
index = 0

for i in range(10, 0, -1):
    b.append(a[index:index+i])
    index += i

for j in b:
    print(j)
```

which will output this

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
[1 2 3 4 5]
[1 2 3 4]
[1 2 3]
[1 2]
[1]
```